# Sphere image texture is distorted by shadow map - OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, geometry, shadow

I am doing shadow mapping in OpenGL using the fixed-function pipeline, not shaders. I have managed to implement the shadow maps fine, but without textures on the thing that shadows are cast on.

When I add my texture to my sphere just before it renders, it appears distorted. I can move around my light source and it distorts it more/less depending on the position of the light source.

What are the possible causes of this?

This is my glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_DIFFUSE, white);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_SPECULAR, white);

```
//Calculate texture matrix for projection
//This matrix takes us from eye space to the light's clip space
//It is postmultiplied by the inverse of the current view matrix when specifying texgen
static MATRIX4X4 biasMatrix(0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
                            0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
                            0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f,
                            0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f);    //bias from [-1, 1] to [0, 1]
MATRIX4X4 textureMatrix=biasMatrix*lightProjectionMatrix*lightViewMatrix;

//Set up texture coordinate generation.
glTexGeni(GL_S, GL_TEXTURE_GEN_MODE, GL_EYE_LINEAR);
glTexGenfv(GL_S, GL_EYE_PLANE, textureMatrix.GetRow(0));
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_GEN_S);

glTexGeni(GL_T, GL_TEXTURE_GEN_MODE, GL_EYE_LINEAR);
glTexGenfv(GL_T, GL_EYE_PLANE, textureMatrix.GetRow(1));
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_GEN_T);

glTexGeni(GL_R, GL_TEXTURE_GEN_MODE, GL_EYE_LINEAR);
glTexGenfv(GL_R, GL_EYE_PLANE, textureMatrix.GetRow(2));
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_GEN_R);

glTexGeni(GL_Q, GL_TEXTURE_GEN_MODE, GL_EYE_LINEAR);
glTexGenfv(GL_Q, GL_EYE_PLANE, textureMatrix.GetRow(3));
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_GEN_Q);

//Bind & enable shadow map texture
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, shadowMapTexture);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

//Enable shadow comparison
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_COMPARE_MODE_ARB, GL_COMPARE_R_TO_TEXTURE);

//Shadow comparison should be true (ie not in shadow) if r<=texture
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_COMPARE_FUNC_ARB, GL_LEQUAL);

//Shadow comparison should generate an INTENSITY result
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_DEPTH_TEXTURE_MODE_ARB, GL_INTENSITY);

//Set alpha test to discard false comparisons
glAlphaFunc(GL_GEQUAL, 0.99f);
glEnable(GL_ALPHA_TEST);
glColor4f(1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
world->textured = true;
renderObjects();

sun->center = Vertex(lightX, lightY, lightZ);
glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);
glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
  glColor3f(1,1,0);
  glColorMaterial( GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE ) ;  
  glTranslatef(sun->center.x, sun->center.y, sun->center.z);
  sun->lighting = false;
  sun->z = -lightZ +1;
  sun->render();
  glColor3f(1, 1, 1);
glDisable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);

//Disable textures and texgen
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_GEN_S);
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_GEN_T);
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_GEN_R);
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_GEN_Q);
//Restore other states
glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);
glDisable(GL_ALPHA_TEST);

//reset matrices
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glPopMatrix();
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glPopMatrix();
update();
```

Render Objects:

```
void Widget::renderObjects()
{
  glPushMatrix();
    glColor4f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    glPushMatrix();
      //glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_EMISSION, emission); 
      //glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_SPECULAR, specular); 
      arcBall->q.rotate();
      world->render();
      glPushMatrix();
        torso->frame = frame;
        torso->draw();
        glPushMatrix();
          renderParticles();
        glPopMatrix();
      glPopMatrix();
    glPopMatrix();
  glPopMatrix();
}
```

And for kicks, here's my first & second pass too.

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
lightPosition = VECTOR3D(lightX, lightY, lightZ);
glLoadIdentity();
gluLookAt(  lightPosition.x, lightPosition.y, lightPosition.z,
            0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
            0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, lightViewMatrix);




glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadMatrixf(lightProjectionMatrix);

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadMatrixf(lightViewMatrix);

//Use viewport the same size as the shadow map
glViewport(0, 0, shadowMapSize, shadowMapSize);

//Draw back faces into the shadow map
glCullFace(GL_FRONT);

//Disable color writes, and use flat shading for speed
glShadeModel(GL_FLAT);
glColorMask(0, 0, 0, 0);
//Draw the scene
renderObjects();

//Read the depth buffer into the shadow map texture
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, shadowMapTexture);
glCopyTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, shadowMapSize, shadowMapSize);

//restore states
glCullFace(GL_BACK);
glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
glColorMask(1, 1, 1, 1);


//2nd pass - Draw from camera's point of view
glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadMatrixf(cameraProjectionMatrix);

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadMatrixf(cameraViewMatrix);

glViewport(0, 0, windowWidth, windowHeight);

//Use dim light to represent shadowed areas
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_POSITION, VECTOR4D(lightPosition));
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_AMBIENT, white*0.2f);
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_DIFFUSE, white*0.2f);
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_SPECULAR, black);
glEnable(GL_LIGHT1);
glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);

renderObjects();
```

Comment: What do you mean diffuse texture? I don't render my textures when I do my first/second pass of rendering. Only the third pass is when I load them, and then bind and render them on the objects.

Comment: It was too much work to explain in a comment, so I wrote an answer with some pseudo-code.

Comment: I added some code to show you what I currently do for my final render pass.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are doing this using the fixed-function pipeline, I imagine you are using texture matrices (a per-Texture Image Unit state).

Are you sure the texture matrices are setup appropriately when you try to sample from your regular textures? It sounds to me like you are using the same matrices for your diffuse texture as you used for your shadow map. Generally you would want identity matrices when sampling everything except the shadow map.

#### Consider the following example:

```
glActiveTexture (GL_TEXTURE0);
glMatrixMode    (GL_TEXTURE);
glLoadMatrixf   (shadow_matrix);

glBindTexture   (shadow_map);

// Draw shadow pass

glBindTexture   (diffuse_map);

// Draw the base diffuse pass
```

In this example, the second draw is still being affected by the matrix you had to load for the shadow map. You can solve this two ways:

1. Dedicate a Texture Image Unit to sampling your shadow map
2. Push/pop or load an identity texture matrix after you apply your shadow map

Comment: When I load the identity matrix, my lighting goes, though.

Comment: @Gentatsu: I was mistaken in my original assumption... you are using `glTexGen (...)` based on a texture matrix. It is a very similar concept, though to fix this what you need to do is call `glDisable (GL_TEXTURE_GEN_S)`, `glDisable (GL_TEXTURE_GEN_T)`, `glDisable (GL_TEXTURE_GEN_R)` and `glDisable (GL_TEXTURE_GEN_Q)` *after* your shadow pass.

Comment: Ah. I just noticed something. My texture is only showing a portion of my texture at a time.

Comment: Hmm, that gives me lighting back, but not now my shadows do not show. I'm calling the disable BEFORE I render my objects now.

Comment: @Gentatsu: It needs to be done inside of `renderObjects ()` actually. I assume that the three passes you were discussing are done in that function. The first pass needs to have texture coordinate generation enabled but the third (and probably second) do not. If you could show the implementation of `renderObjects (...)` that would help.

Comment: I added my renderObjects and my first and second pass, although I'm not sure if it'll help.

Comment: So you're saying I should enable them directly before and after I do my texel coords?

Comment: @Gentatsu: I am saying that you need texture coordinate generation when you draw your shadow map, but you don't need it when you draw any other texture. That would mean somewhere inbetween the very first snippet of code that you included in your question and the two passes that you just added, you need to make the `glDisable (...)` calls I mentioned earlier.

Comment: I tried using glActiveTexture, and assigned 0 to my shadow texture, and 1 for all others. That kinda fixed it. It's still distorted. But my shadows show up on the texture now. Depending on my light position, some of the sphere is completely in the dark, though.

Comment: I only do glTexGen in the third pass, though?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67246/discussion-between-gentatsu-and-andon-m-coleman).